# TSQL Rolling Sum with Rows from Last Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with rows for each day and and INT column 1/0 to indicate absence on that. I need to calculate rolling sum of absence days for each row. I am using SQL 2016.

The date on the row will be the last day of the month and the first day will be something between 27 to 30 days in the past depending on months like February.

I have tried using

`SUM () OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER by col2 ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)`

which will fail when we have months like February. What I need is a way to have

`ROWS BETWEEN N PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW`

where N is calculated based on the date on the row and the start date a month ago.

[image]

For my benefit to try this, I have the example script here:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data

create table #data
(
emp_name varchar(50)
,calendar_date date
,absence INT default(0)
)

-- script to populate table
;WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    select 0 as n
    union
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
insert into #data(emp_name, calendar_date)
SELECT 'Dorris Johanssen' as emp_name, cast(DATEADD(dd, n, '2019-01-01') as date) calendar_date
FROM Tally
union
SELECT 'Broderick Snob' as emp_name, cast(DATEADD(dd, n, '2019-01-01') as date) calendar_date
FROM Tally

-- Populate Absence
update #data set absence = 1 where emp_name = 'Dorris Johanssen' and calendar_date between '2020-02-25' and '2020-03-02'
--update #data set absence = 1 where emp_name = 'Dorris Johanssen' and calendar_date between '2020-03-23' and '2020-04-07'
update #data set absence = 1 where emp_name = 'Broderick Snob' and calendar_date between '2020-03-23' and '2020-04-07'

-- Rolling sum of absence for the last one month
select *
, dateadd(dd, 1, dateadd(mm, -1, calendar_date)) as  date_one_month_before
, datediff(dd, dateadd(dd, 1, dateadd(mm, -1, calendar_date)), calendar_date) day_diff
, sum(absence) over (Partition by emp_name order by calendar_date rows between 30 preceding and current row) abs_day 
from #data 
where emp_name = 'Dorris Johanssen'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a cumulative sum for the current month:

```
select t.*,
       sum(absence) over (partition by emp_name, eomonth(calendar_date) order by calendar_date)
from t
```

Comment: Gordon, if we take the highlighted dates from my question, for calendar_date 24/03/2020, I would like the cumulative total of absence from 25/02/2020 - 24/03/2020. Hope this is helpful.